# Maximize $\exp(-x^2 - y)$ subject to $y^2 = \exp (-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, optimization

The problem is to find the local maxima of $f(x,y) = \exp (-x^2 - y)$ subject to the constraint $M=\{(x,y)\mid y^2 = \exp (-x^2)\}$.

I've tried substitution:
\begin{align*}
y^2 = \exp (-x^2)
&\Rightarrow f(x,y) = y^2 \cdot \exp (-y)\\
&\Rightarrow f' = 2y \exp (-y) - y^2 \exp (-y) = (2 - y) \cdot y \cdot \exp (-y) = 0\\
&\Rightarrow y = 0,2.
\end{align*}
The exponential curve does not reach the $x$-axis, thus the solution $y = 0$ is useless. When $y=2$, the constraint $y^2 = \exp (-x^2)$ gives $\ln 4 = - x^2$. But $- x^2$ is inverted parabola and takes non-positive values for any $x$. On the other hand, $\ln 4 > \ln e = 1 > 0$, i.e. $\ln 4$ lies above x-axis. Again useless $y$.

I'm confused. I suppose that local max may be achieved in non-stationary point but how to find them?

Answer (score 3):

$y^2 = \exp(-x^2)$ means that $0 < |y| \leq 1$, so $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ and $y \not= 0$. the derivative you calculated is non-positive for $y$ in $[-1;0]$ and non-negative for $y$ in $[0,1]$ hence the function is decreasing on the first interval and increasing on the second one, so it takes its maximum either at $y = -1$ or $y = 1$.  you can easily see that the value at $-1$ is the greater one, hence this is the maximum

in general if you want to find maximum of a function on a given interval you need to check not only the points at which the derivative vanishes but also the endpoints and points at which the function is not differentiable (if such points exist)

Comment: oh, and note that for $y \in [-1;1]$ and not equal to $0$ the 'right' $x$ exists